# I want to change the background div color while hovering another div but it doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I want to hover any of the div that have the `id` of symbol and change the color of `#bg`, how do i do it?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="symbol1"></div>
    <div id="symbol2"></div>
    <div id="symbol3"></div>
    <div id="symbol4"></div>
</div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

I tried to use this but it didn't work. I also used `+` and `>` and just a space too.

```
#symbol3:hover ~ #bg{
    background-color:red;
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_4

Comment: Put the css on the outer div: `#container:hover + #bg { background-color:red; }` ??

Comment: Welcome! The problem is all of the selectors you are using assumes that `#bg` is a direct sibling of your `symbol` elements, however, `#bg` is a sibling of the parent `#container` there's not a CSS way to target a sibling of a parent element. `:has()` might get close.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to combine the `:has()` selector and the target attribute selector `[attribute*="value"]` which selects any element that has a substring `value` in its `attribute`.

```css
#bg {
  /* just to display #bg div */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

#container:has([id*="symbol"]:hover) + #bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="symbol1">1</div>
  <div id="symbol2">2</div>
  <div id="symbol3">3</div>
  <div id="symbol4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

`#container:has([id*="symbol"]:hover) + #bg` means to check for `#container` that has an `id` with a value containing `symbol` while it is being hovered on, then to select the `#bg` placed immediately after it.

Read more on CSS selectors: [w3schools CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

Comment: Nice use of selectors 

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that which disinfor has stated.
If you move the `#bg` div to be outside but prior to the `#container` div then you can use the below.
The `:has()` selector will select a `#bg` element that is followed by a `#container` element of which has a `div#symbol3` being hovered.
If you can not change the structure of the HTML, I believe you would to use some sort of JS.

```css
#bg:has(+ #container div#symbol3:hover) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">0</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="symbol1">1</div>
  <div id="symbol2">2</div>
  <div id="symbol3">3</div>
  <div id="symbol4">4</div>
</div>
```